# Why wrap a function reference into an anonymous function can correct 'this' point to?

Tags: javascript, scope

Why wrap a function reference into an anonymous function can correct 'this' point to?

```
var logger = {
  x: 0,
  updateCount: function () {
    this.x++;
    console.log( this.x );
    console.log( "Now I'm pointing to : " + this );
  }
}
```

when I call like this

```
btn.addEventListener('click', logger.updateCount );

// may work like below
function cb() {
  console.log(this);
}

addEventListener('click', cb) {

  // this --> DOM element

  cb(); //=> console.log(this) --> DOM element

}
```

But, When i wrap `logger.updateCount` inside an anonymous function can corrent 'this' ?

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    logger.updateCount(); //=> this -- point to 'logger' object
});
```

How come?

Comment: `logger.updateCount.bind(this)` use this to pass reference of this

Comment: @murli2308, You should answer this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "imagine" how it would look to the inside of `btn.addEventListener`, probably like:

```
function addEventListener( eventString, callback ) {

   // check the event
   // if all is good
   // set up an event object
   // call back
   callback(eventObject);

}
```

From this, you see that `addEventListener` only knows there is a callback function, but doesn't know if its `this` should be a specific object, or not.

And the way JS works, if just assumes that if it finds some object before the dot (like in the second example `logger.updateCount()`) it uses it as `this`, but if it doesn't... then you need to `bind` it to one, like:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', logger.updateCount.bind(logger) );
```

Comment: bind `this` not the `logger`

Comment: and what is `this` when the code executes in the global context?

Answer (score 0):

(this) in JavaScript is resolved based on the call site (how the function is invoked).

1. If the function is invoked as a method meaning if it is used like .func() then  will be passed as this.  logger.updateCount() is called in the event listener immaterial of from where it is called updateCount method will always receive logger object as this. this is hard-bound to logger object.
2. If the function object is passed as event handler or as a callback. The this is bound to DOM element where the event is triggered.
3. The this context that a function receives can be changed by using bind method as below:
    logger.updateCount.bind() 
   In above case updateCount will always receives the targetObject that you sent as parameter as this context